# Memory Leak Native Array and UnSafeList

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine, memory-leaks, unsafe

I am using Unity [Native array](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.html) that contains [unsafelists](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@0.12/api/Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeList-1.html). And Fallback allocation consume too much time. There must memory leak but I couldn't figure out. Here is my code:

```cs
NativeArray < SVerticeKnowledge > SVerticeKnowledges = new NativeArray < SVerticeKnowledge > (VerticeKnowledges.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
for (int i = 0; i < SVerticeKnowledges.Length; i++) {

  UnsafeList < float3 > PosForNode = new UnsafeList < float3 > (VerticeKnowledges[i].PosForNode.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
  UnsafeList < float > Weights = new UnsafeList < float > (VerticeKnowledges[i].Weights.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
  UnsafeList < TransformData > transformDatas = new UnsafeList < TransformData > (VerticeKnowledges[i].ConnectedNode.Count, Allocator.TempJob);
  for (int j = 0; j < VerticeKnowledges[i].PosForNode.Count; j++) {
    PosForNode.AddNoResize(VerticeKnowledges[i].PosForNode[j]);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < VerticeKnowledges[i].Weights.Count; j++) {
    Weights.AddNoResize(VerticeKnowledges[i].Weights[j]);
  }
  for (int j = 0; j < VerticeKnowledges[i].ConnectedNode.Count; j++) {
    transformDatas.AddNoResize(new TransformData(VerticeKnowledges[i].ConnectedNode[j].position, VerticeKnowledges[i].ConnectedNode[j].rotation, VerticeKnowledges[i].ConnectedNode[j].localScale));
  }

  SVerticeKnowledges[i] = new SVerticeKnowledge(PosForNode, Weights, transformDatas, new TransformData(transform.position, transform.rotation, transform.localScale));

}

var job = new NewPosCalculation() {
  VerticeKnowledges = SVerticeKnowledges
};

JobHandle jobHandle = job.Schedule(SVerticeKnowledges.Length, 1);
jobHandle.Complete();

for (int i = 0; i < VerticeKnowledges.Count; i++) {
  MeshVertices[i] = VerticeKnowledges[i].NewPos;

}
foreach(SVerticeKnowledge vertice_knowledge in SVerticeKnowledges) {
  vertice_knowledge.ConnectedNodeLocalToWorld.Dispose();
  vertice_knowledge.PosForNode.Dispose();
  vertice_knowledge.Weights.Dispose();

}
SVerticeKnowledges.Dispose();
```

I want to fix memory leak or high time consuming.

Comment: you're issue seems to be with `Allocator.TempJob`

Comment: also make sure that all code returns and no error happen before you call your `Dispose` functions, also ensure that the object you're calling `Dispose` on is not null.

Comment: Best to use a `memory profiler` in either visual studio or inside of unity

Comment: What is `NativeArray<T>` is it the Unity type [`Unity.Collections.NativeArray<T0>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Unity.Collections.NativeArray_1.html), or something else?  And what is `UnsafeList<T>` ? Is it [`Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeList<T>`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.collections@0.12/api/Unity.Collections.LowLevel.Unsafe.UnsafeList-1.html)?  And what is `SVerticeKnowledge`?  Is it a managed type, or an unmanaged type?  Can you [edit] your question to share a [mcve] showing your types and indicating the libraries you are using?

Comment: Yes LowLevel.Unsafe. Yes collections nativearray .And yes struct is unmanaged. And dispose is called there is no error. Just consuming too much time and looks like memory leak. What is wrong with Allocator.TempJob ?

Comment: Then can you share a [mcve] showing your types `SVerticeKnowledge`, `TransformData` and `NewPosCalculation`?  Finally, how do you know there is a memory leak?

Comment: Also, how large are the arrays and lists when you are encountering unacceptable performance?  I.e. what is `SVerticeKnowledges.Length`, and what are the maximum typical values of `PosForNode.Count`, `Weights.Count` and `ConnectedNode.Count`?  And what is the total count for your three types of `UnsafeList<T>`, summed across all entries in `SVerticeKnowledges`?

Comment: It shows the problem on profiler, when allocator is persistent. There is 100k malloc call from 22ms. How can I optimize this